# Teradata - jdbc - suppress zero from decimal scale part

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, teradata

when I am selecting the value from the database I am receiving it with non suppressed zeros in decimal scale. For example:
Value: 0.5 - data type format is DECIMAL(5,5)

```
select cast(%s as  FORMAT 'ZZZZZ,ZZZZZZ') from bla
```

return me value 0.50000 instead of 0.5 as I am expecting

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I think that the format should be `'ZZZZZ.ZZZZZZ'`.  Note: the `.` is the radix (i.e. decimal point) character, but you have used the separator character.

Comment: You can trim the 0's using: `Trim(BOTH '0' FROM %s)`

Comment: Or `CAST(x AS NUMBER)`

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(0.50000 as float FORMAT 'ZZZZZ.ZZZZZZ')
```